# Access Gridview from a Javascript function within Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, function, gridview

I would like to have access to the column:
`<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ContactGestionnaire"></dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>` in my Javascript function OnUpdateClick().

Below is an snippet from my aspx page (the full source is 50+ columns):

> ```
> <dx:DxGridView_RowEdit ID="Grid" ClientInstanceName="Grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridOds" 
>     KeyFieldName="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
>                 <Styles Header-CssClass="gridHeader" Header-ForeColor="White">
>             </Styles>
>             <Settings ShowTitlePanel="False" ShowFilterRow="true" />
> ```

```
    <Columns>

                <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="IdContrat" Caption="Contrat" CellStyle-CssClass="required">
                    <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="ContratOds" ValueField="Id" TextField="LibelleContratVertuozUnique">
                    </PropertiesComboBox>
                </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LibelleNation" CellStyle-CssClass="required" Width="50px">
                </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LibelleNationUnique" ReadOnly="true">
                </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ContactGestionnaire">
                    <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="ContactOds" ValueField="Id" TextField="LibelleContactVertuozUnique"
                        ValueType="System.Int32" ClientSideEvents-Init="combobox_AddNullItem">
                    </PropertiesComboBox>
                </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ContactExploitant">
                    <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="ContactOds" ValueField="Id" TextField="LibelleContactVertuozUnique"
                        ValueType="System.Int32" ClientSideEvents-Init="combobox_AddNullItem">
                    </PropertiesComboBox>
                </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

            </Columns>

    <Templates>
        <EditForm>
                <dx:ASPxPageControl runat="server" ID="pageControl">
                    <TabPages>
                        <dx:TabPage Text="Patrimoine" Visible="true">
                            <ContentCollection>
                                <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
                                    <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="Editors" ReplacementType="EditFormEditors"
                                        runat="server">
                                    </dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>
                        </TabPages>
        </dx:ASPxPageControl>

                <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="TemplateReplacementCancel" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton" runat="server"/>
             <dx:AspxHyperLink runat="server" ID="Update" NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);" Text="Mise a jour" Font-Underline="True">
                <ClientSideEvents Click="OnUpdateClick"/>
              </dx:AspxHyperLink>

        </EditForm>
    </Templates>

    </dx:DxGridView_RowEdit>
```

I have a DevExpress library and I am using Template EditForm and HyperLink for calling the Javascript function.

Now my function:

```
function OnUpdateClick(s,e) {
    var grdId = document.getElementById('<%=Grid.ClientID%>');

    // Now my if read in c# for understand how it works :
    if(Grid.Columns["ContactGestionnaire"]== null) {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure ? ");
        if(r == true) {
            Grid.UpdateEdit();
        }
    }
    Grid.UpdateEdit();
}
```

But I can't do this in the backend code because of a request from the project manager.

Can you help me to have access to the Grid in my Javascript?

Thank you for your advice and sorry for my bad bad English.

Comment: mind to post ur html code also?

Comment: I edit my post with few aspx code of my gridview . I don't share ObjectSource It's basic objectsource called a method return List in another class.